# i do not have android and ios folder-react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

no android and ios folder.

I do not know what's the problem.

and I also want to add a custom fonts in my app.

I am new to r-native.please help

Comment: Run npx react-native init AwesomeProject to create a project with native code
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're developing your app with Expo. When you start [setting up your environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) on react native documentation you can choose between Expo CLI or React Native CLI. You chose expo client. I already build a react native project with expo and I don't have neither any ios or android folders. I guess it is normal for Expo to not have these directories since expo doesn't exactly interact with native modules. And that's the same reason I recommend you to start your projects with the React Native CLI, because you will not be able to use those packages that use native libraries.

Comment: You can setup an android emulator, an ios emulator (if you're using macOS) or connect your device, and configure react-native to connect to these instances